# Structs method is giving undefined while importing in other package

Tags: go, struct, methods, package

I have a model file in which there is a struct method. That method I want to use in my controller. But it is saying "*GetBookings not declared by package models*". I am very new to Golang, may be it is a silly question still I'm stuck with it. If someone can rectify my code or may be give a another option how to use struct methods in another file, would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**controller**

```
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/Coddyy/beautyfly/pkg/models"
)

func GetBookings(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    bookings, err := models.GetBookings()
    res, _ := json.Marshal(bookings)
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

**model**

```
package models

import (
    "database/sql"

    "github.com/Coddyy/beautyfly/pkg/entities"
)

type BookingModel struct {
    Db *sql.DB
}

func init() {

}

func (bookingModel *BookingModel) GetBookings() ([]entities.Booking, error) {
    rows, err := bookingModel.Db.Query("SELECT * FROM bookings")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        bookings := []entities.Booking{}
        for rows.Next() {
            var id int64
            var customer_ids string
            var date string
            var time string
            var service_ids string
            var comments string
            err2 := rows.Scan(&id, &customer_ids, &date, &time, &service_ids, &comments)
            if err2 != nil {
                return nil, err2
            } else {
                booking := entities.Booking{id, customer_ids, date, time, service_ids, 
                comments}
                bookings = append(bookings, booking)
            }
        }
        return bookings, nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call `GetBookings()` method of `BookingModel` you need an instance of `BookingModel` struct. Then you can call any method of `BookingModel` on that instance:

```
func GetBookings(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var bookingModel = models.BookingModel{}

    bookings, err := bookingModel.GetBookings()
    // always do error checking
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    res, err := json.Marshal(bookings)
    // always do error checking
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir@ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV.  Solved